# Http UrlConnection Java for File Download

Tags: java

We have to connect to a `asp.net` server to download media items.
We've got this code:

```
URLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        String localTempPath = SettingsManager.getInstance().getLocalTempMediaItemFilePath(loadingItem);
        URL serverPath = new URL(SettingsManager.getInstance().getServerMediaItemFilePath(loadingItem));

        urlConnection = serverPath.openConnection();
        String urlParameters = "http://tempuri.org/";

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverPath.openConnection();

        connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        for (String cookie:cookies.keySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie + "=" + cookies.get(cookie));
        }   //only one Cookie: ASPNET_SessionId=...

        connection.connect();

        int response = connection.getResponseCode();

        File f = new File (localTempPath);
        f.createNewFile();
        if (f.exists()){
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);

            //Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            int totalsize = connection.getContentLength();
            int downloadedSize = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte [1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
                fileOutput.write(buffer,0,bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            }
            fileOutput.close();
        }

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
    }
```

We have to send the **Session-Cookie** to the server but we always get a `404:java.io.FileNotFoundException`: http://possuite.emmgt.at/v30/dataservice/MediaItem/6629.mi

Comment: On which statement is the exception thrown??

Comment: Side note: your code is doing **way too many** things within one method. Consider reading about the "single responsibility principle" and the "single abstraction principle". Your code could definitely benefit from that.

Comment: Pretty normal code to download a file.

Comment: `f.createNewFile();
        if (f.exists())`. That is bad code. Better just remove.